# How do I use a function multiple times in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops, arguments, call

I am having some trouble with some code. When I use a function once calling it again doesn't appear to call the function again.

```
credit=0
x=1
d=1
def sum1():
    global x
    global credit
while x>0:
    g=int(input("Press 1 to continue inputting money or press 0 to select    and item"))
    if g==1:
        inpt=int(input("Please insert 10p, 20p, 50p, or £1 (100p) coins   into the machine."))
        credit=credit+inpt
    else:
        print("You have "+str(credit)+" pence in your credit balance")
        x=0
sum1()
print("something")
sum1()
```

This is part of my code, running the function once seems to make the other one not work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are using functions wildly incorrectly.

Comment: you just made a function to define some variables as `global`. So why you made that function at the first place? You don't do anything in that function.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the use of the function in your code. If it's simply returning the global values, why not do just that in your conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to write the following code:

```
credit=0
x=1
d=1
def sum1():
    global x
    global credit
    while x>0:
        g=int(input("Press 1 to continue inputting money or press 0 to select    and item"))
        if g==1:
            inpt=int(input("Please insert 10p, 20p, 50p, or £1 (100p) coins   into the machine."))
            credit=credit+inpt
        else:
            print("You have "+str(credit)+" pence in your credit balance")
            x=0
sum1()
print("something")
sum1()
```

When you call sum1() for the first time, based on your input (when you press 0), value of x is set to zero (x = 0). So next time, when you call sum1(), the condition inside while loop is False (while x > 0), so you don't see anything.

If you use a print statement immediately after defining the function, you will see that it works twice (the function gets called twice).